# WSGI vs ASGI server with hybrid sync/async Django app

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, gunicorn, asgi

I have a Django app with multiple async views doing some http requests, but some part are still synchronous like most of the middlewares.
So there will always be a small performance penalty with the sync/async switch when handling incoming requests.

It is possible to run this app on both WSGI or ASGI gunicorn server (using uvicorn worker), but I don't really understand which one is better for an hybrid sync/async Django app.
In both cases it seems that there is blocking code in a thread.